# RMI for low bandwidth - alternative?

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, rmi

I'm building a client-server connection, which will target low bandwidth later.
At the moment I'm using sockets. But now I cam around RMI - which seems to provide my needs:
call a server-side method from the client-side.

My question is: should I go deeper to RMI, or are there even better approaches which I might not know about?

My goal is especially to have some methods on the server, which I then can execute by the client. So that my "message-queue" must not be static, as it has to be when just using socket and getting the strings from read().

Comment: If you *really* want low-bandwidth, you can roll a custom-made  protocol specific to what you need to do such that there are predefined message types for each "method" you need to invoke remotely... but no I don't think that will be necessary, at least not now. RMI should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't write such a thing from scratch.

RMI means a Java-only client and RMI or CORBA as a wire protocol.

Simple and open have won: why not consider an HTTP, web-based service exposing methods to clients via SOAP, REST, or RPC-XML?  Those can be called by non-Java clients; they're available on the web; they offer the same advantages as RMI.

I can't see why anyone would start with raw RMI anymore.  It's lost the argument, just like CORBA did.

Comment: Indeed SOAP looks very interesting and seems to also fit my needs. Will have a closer look as I will be deploying everything to a webapp at the end anyway.

Comment: You can't really say that CORBA 'lost the argument' when there is an ORB in every JRE shipped; when RMI/IIOP is the mandated protocol for J2EE; when an ORB is the basis of most J2EE implementations; and when you cite RMI/IIOP in your own answer as a solution.

Comment: I think it's still a valid statement, because web services are far more commonly used that CORBA.  Simple and open have won.  An ORB ships with every JRE for legacy reasons.  CORBA was still significant back in 1995.  It's not now.

Comment: But is that really true? You have to count most J2EE installations as CORBA installations. Do you have any facts to support these assertions?

Comment: Under the covers perhaps.  All I know is that CORBA vendors like Iona are gone.  Complexity, interoperability, and proprietary standards put them out of business.  I never, ever hear about anyone saying that they're going to start a new CORBA installation.  I do see that everyone is either using web services or trying to figure out how to get there.  Is Amazon using CORBA?  No, they expose web services to their client base. SOAP or REST, take your pick.  Is that fact enough for you?

Comment: The CORBA vendors have become J2EE vendors. Why do you think Sun was forced to change the J2EE protocol from JRMP to IIOP? Industry pressure. My question is about the proportion of J2EE sites to Web Services sites, and it would be answered by statistics, not by selective and unsupported anecdotal evidence.

Comment: OK, where's yours?  And while you're at it, let us know if you have a CORBA affiliation that would explain the ax you're grinding.